# jQuery fadeIn creating white spots / specks on images in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, debugging, fadein

This is really driving me up the wall. I've got a client who *has* to have his site work exactly the same in IE as other browsers that actually work like FF, Chrome and Safari, but I can't seem to get IE to play ball.

Here are the log in details for the site I'm working on:

u: millbank
p: 123654

Have a look at this page in IE:

http://tiger.directrouter.co.uk/~millbank/?page_id=21

You'll see white spots appear on the image on the RHS on load and the first quote doesn't fade in as it should do.

I have conditionals for CSS for IE and have tried adding a plain colour background to the #bgimg div, but it makes no difference it seems.

Is there anything else I can try? (please)...

Thanks

osu

Comment: giving away the credentials on forums is not a good idea ...

Comment: I think we are trusty here... :)

Comment: @Osu the images are the main problem right? They do not appear like in moz and others. right? (First tought, tried to use jQ 1.6.2?) ... And, please, next time tell us what IE v. is in question.

Comment: @roXon and @Spudley - it's Internet Explorer 7+, I'm having the issue with pretty much all IE versions. I think Spudley is right in that it's IE's poor support for transparency and fear that I won't be able to get around it other than living with it. Will try the latest version of jQuery like you say roXon. Any idea why the first quote isn't fading in properly? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may have to do with IE's filters.  See http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showpost.php?p=161962&postcount=3 for a similar issue.

Comment: This technique works - thanks for pointing it out! Just changed the image in the link I posted and it's working!

Comment: The only thing that I'm struggling with now is the first quote not fading in on IE7+. So many issues with this browser, it's ridiculous!

Comment: Osu. I know how you feel. We hate Microsoft too. Just be clever.  Add lots of *if* statements to check browser version and add custom workarounds for IE. Even replacing png images in your case with jpg. Google is a good place to find workaround code snippets and even clever suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified the IE version you're using, but I suspect IE8, right? (or lower??)

IE8 has appallingly bad support for transparency. It uses non-standard ways of achieving it, and gives poor quality results with it in a lot of cases, especially when it is used in conjunction with images, rather than text.

JQuery does an incredible job of abstracting the differences between browsers away from the developer, but it can't actually fix features in IE that are fundamentally broken like this one.

The bottom line is that this may be something you just have to live with. If you want to use `fadeIn()`, either avoid fading in images, or accept that it's going to look busted in IE.

It is possible to mitigate the problems to some degree by fine tuning the images themselves - if you have any pixels which are solid black or white, try adjusting them so they're not quite pure black or white; this may help. But even with a perfectly adjusted graphic, IE can still get things painfully wrong, so even if it does work for you in this case, please don't consider that to be perfect cure.

Another thing you can try (but again not guaranteed to solve all of IE's problems) is if you're fading in a block which contains images and other elements, then do the fade in for the image separately to the rest of the content.

Comment: thanks for your help, seems reuploading images without pure black in them solved the issue, just trying to sort the first quote not fading in now...